# linear speedup with OpenMP

Tags: c++, openmp

I have this simple code testing how many times of speedup with more cores assigned, however I didn't observe linear speedup.

```
int main() {
    using u64_t = unsigned long long;
    u64_t n = 1e9;
    u64_t* a = new u64_t[n];
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (u64_t i=0; i<n; ++i) {
        a[i] = i;
    }
}
```

compiled like '`g++ -fopenmp -O3 test.cpp`', and then

```
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=1  # time cost = 4.485s
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=2  # time cost = 2.916s
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=3  # time cost = 2.571s
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=4  # time cost = 2.347s
```

why no linear speedup?

**UPDATE**

system env as follows

[image]

also, `htop` gives me 4 threads, I suspect if hyper-threading is enabled, there might be only 2 physical cores.

I measure the speed using `time ./a.out`, compiled with gnu `g++-7`.

**FOLLOW-UP**

Now I changed the code a bit, as follows

```
int main() {
    using u64_t = unsigned long long;
    u64_t n = 1e9;
    u64_t a[7];
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (u64_t i=0; i<n; ++i) {
        a[i%7] = i;   // a is an array, I know there might be data race here
    }
    cout << a[0] << "," << a[6];
}
```

I tested the above code, but now `omp` version (2.1s) is slower than serial version (1.2s), why?

Comment: How many cores do you have? Real cores. Not threads. This indicates that you have 2 cores and 4 threads.

Comment: @Clearer, it's a mac pro, and `htop` tells me there're 4, also `sysctl -n hw.ncpu` gives me 4, is that right?

Comment: Dunno. I don't own a mac so I don't know what `htop` or `sysctl` returns.

Comment: Please provide information about your system: the CPU model and memory configuration. What's the compiler version. Also describe how you measure time.

Comment: @Zulan updated.

Comment: My previous answer was not related to the problem. Thank you to @Zulan for correcting me.

Comment: Please do not post multiple questions in one. The follow up is much different, the answer there is actually false sharing as per the now-deleted answer by @Clearer. But reasoning about the performance of a known incorrect program (data race) is not really interesting.

Comment: @Zulan, got it, will post a new one, but in my defense actually I'm trying to implement an algo which might have known data race, called hogwild!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is mainly limited by memory bandwidth, since you write one value per operation. Typically there is less memory bandwidth than can be utilized by all cores in parallel.

Doing the math on memory saturation is a bit off from the specs. 
Your system probably has a [i5-5257U](https://ark.intel.com/de/products/84985/Intel-Core-i5-5257U-Processor-3M-Cache-up-to-3_10-GHz) and in that configuration it should have 25.6 GB/s memory bandwidth. You only get to write 3.4 GB/s - for write you often actually use twice that because every write first needs to read the cache line from memory. So between 6.8 GB/s and the theoretical bandwidth there is still a lot of headway, but that's not unheard of. I can't reproduce this since I have no identical hardware. For a more detailed analysis one would have to dig into the generated instructions and hardware performance counters.

Some more remarks:

- I hear apple sometimes aliases `gcc` with `clang`, this may be misleading.
- You should do something with `a` after the loop to prevent the compiler optimizing it away.
- Your time measurement includes application the non-parallel setup and `new ...`, so you are heavily affected [Amdal's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law). Consider timing only the parallel portion with `omp_get_wtime()`.

All that said, your processor only has two cores (four hw-threads), and you should not expect a speedup beyond two threads anyway.

Comment: +1 terrific & professional answer. A few quick questions: 1) I install this gnu `gcc` compiler myself, so guaranteed it's not mac `clang`. 2) what do you mean by `prevent the compiler optimizing it away`? Optimize WHAT away? 3) yes, the way I timed it will count in `new`,  but this `new` operation cost is negligible.

Comment: I updated the original question with a FOLLOW-UP, parallel version is slower than serial version, could you please give me a hint why?

Comment: Please avoid follow-ups which can be questions on their own and the original question has already been answered.